# Live Updating Matplotlib Plot with scrolling x-axis

Tags: python

In Python I have a code put together which pulls data from a CSV (csv looks like the following:)

```html
TimeStamp, ReadCount, Antenna, Protocol, RSSI, EPC, Sensor
09/21/2016 15:24:40.560, 5499, 1, GEN2, -21, E036112D912508B3, 23.78,47.00,0.00,2.21, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:41.138, 5506, 1, GEN2, -9, E036112D912508B3, 23.99,46.00,0.00,2.26, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:41.623, 5513, 1, GEN2, -25, E036112D912508B3, 23.99,46.00,0.00,2.26, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:42.120, 5520, 1, GEN2, -18, E036112D912508B3, 23.78,46.00,0.00,2.26, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:42.633, 5527, 1, GEN2, -12, E036112D912508B3, 23.99,45.00,0.00,2.23, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:43.211, 5534, 1, GEN2, -9, E036112D912508B3, 23.99,46.00,0.00,2.26, (Infinity%)
09/21/2016 15:24:43.744, 5541, 1, GEN2, -16, E036112D912508B3, 23.99,46.00,0.00,2.26, (Infinity%)
```

It then graphs this data - here is the code:

```html
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from datetime import datetime
      
offset = -7.4954
slope = 0.9548

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#07000d')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='#07000d')

ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax1.spines['top'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax1.spines['left'].set_color("#5998ff")
ax1.spines['right'].set_color("#5998ff")
    
def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('SensorLog.csv','r').read()
    dataArray = graph_data.split('\n')

    xar=[]
    yar=[]
    
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if 'TimeStamp' not in eachLine: 
            if len(eachLine)>1:
                t,rc,ant,prot,rssi,epc,temp,ten,powr,unpowr,inf=(eachLine.split(','))         
                time = datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
                clock = time.strftime('%I:%M')
                xs = matplotlib.dates.datestr2num(clock)
                hfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y\n%I:%M:%S %p')

#                Convert tension
                tension = int(float(ten)*float(slope)+float(offset))
                
                xar.append(xs)
                yar.append(tension)
                
    ax1.clear()
    
    ax1.grid(True, color='w')

    plt.ylabel('Tension (lb)',color='w', fontsize=20)
    plt.title('Spiral 1 Tension',color='w', fontsize=26)

       
    ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='w')
    ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='w')
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)

    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    
    ax1.plot (xar,yar, 'c', linewidth=2)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10000)
plt.show()
```

I would like to be able to have the x-axis only show the past 90 seconds of data and not continuously grow to fit all the new data, but instead just push old data out if it is beyond that 90 second range. For example it should show points from 0-90 seconds, and one second later it will show 1-91 seconds.

I've seen some examples but nothing that seems to work for mine. Any help?

Comment: Beside the point, but you may want to look at the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems all you need to do is check each timestamp to see if it is in the last 90 seconds. Have you tried that?